# Eigenvalues of a special $M \times M$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I could not obtain an explicit formula for the eigenvalues of matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
c & a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & c & a & b & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & b \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & c & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It has been claimed that its eigenvalues are
$a + 2\sqrt{bc}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{M+1}) \quad n = 1, 2, ..., M$

Any help?

Comment: Maybe this paper is helpful: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379599001147/1-s2.0-S0024379599001147-main.pdf?_tid=b18e2836-334d-11e4-aa7f-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1409737131_25a6ff4a596e017b050c85c7efda2edc

Comment: Do you mean $m\times m$ matrix? Cause of "$n=1,2,...,m$"

Comment: @Matthias Oh! Yes!

Comment: Hint: compute by induction the determinant of $A_n$, where $A_n$ is your matrix of dimension $n\times n$: develop along one column, you will get a 2nd order recurrence, that you will solve easily. Then replace $a$ with $a-\lambda$ and solve for eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matrix has constant diagonals it is called [*Toeplitz matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) and if a matrix that has nonzero elements only on the main diagonal, the first diagonal below this, and the first diagonal above the main diagonal called *[tridiagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)*.
So this matrixclass called *tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices*.

As you have written there is a special form for [eigenvalues of tridiagonal Toeplitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues) matrices.

> The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $$A= \begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 & 0
>  & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ c & a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & c & a & b &
>  0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
>  & b \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & c & a \end{pmatrix}, $$ with $a \neq 0
>  \neq c$ are given by $\lambda_j = b + 2a \sqrt{c/a} \cos \left(
>  \frac{j \pi}{n+1} \right)$ and $$x_j =  \begin{pmatrix}  
>  (c/a)^{1/2}\sin(1j\pi /(n+1)) \\   (c/a)^{2/2}\sin(2j\pi /(n+1)) \\  
>  (c/a)^{3/2}\sin(3j\pi /(n+1)) \\   \vdots \\  (c/a)^{n/2}\sin(nj\pi
>  /(n+1)) \\  \end{pmatrix} $$ for $j=1,2,\dots,n$, and conclude that
>    $A$ is diagonalizable.

You can find the proof in

> C. D. Meyer, *Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra*, SIAM, 2004.

at pages 514–516. You can find a pdf version the book [here](http://digidownload.libero.it/aj_music_web/Matrix%20Analysis%20And%20Applied%20Linear%20Algebra.pdf).

Comment: There it is! Great!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $m=2$ this seems to be correct:
Solving
$$\left|\begin{pmatrix}a-\lambda&b\\c&a-\lambda \end{pmatrix}\right| =0$$
$$a^2-2a\lambda+\lambda^2-bc=0$$
$$\lambda=a\pm\sqrt{bc}$$
And $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ for $n=1,2$

Maybe an induction can help...